# Como detectar dos colisiones al mismo tiempo?

Tags: c#, animación, unity2d

Mi problema es que quiero que al colisionar con "Fire" se active la animacion de "ContactWithFire" pero que tambien valide si al estar ejecutandose esa animacion collisiona con "Escaleras"

```
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision){
            if(collision.CompareTag("Fire")){
            Animacion.Play("ContactWithFire");
            IsFire = true;
               if(collision.CompareTag("Escaleras") && IsFire == true){
                GetKeyWithFire();
               } 
        }
    
    }

    void GetKeyWithFire(){
        Debug.Log("Is WORKING");
        IsFire = false;
    }
```

Comment: Y ese código no funciona?

Comment: Tristemente no );

Comment: ¿Sería mucho pedir que coloques todo el código necesario para que cualquier usuario pueda reproducir tu escenario?

Comment: Según yo no debería entrar a ningún if...es así?? o te entra en el primero pero no en el segundo?

Comment: ¿Y animación qué se supone que es? ¿Un `Animator`?

Comment: solo entra al segundo